# Parsing datetime with millisecond

Tags: c#

I am parsing this:

> 20/11/2013 9:08:58 603

with this code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"20/11/2013 9:08:58 603", @"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss FFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why does it fail ?

Comment: The month "20" does not exist. Your format is not ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the format to this `"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss FFF"`